# MySql count the total number of the row with a value that occurs at least two times

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the total number of different class_id in which at least two students who share the same the birthday.

```
class_id      student_id     birthday 
1                30          1994-10-01
1                23          1994-01-01
1                19          1994-02-01
1                11          1994-03-01
2                9           1994-02-01
2                43          1994-03-01
3                41          1994-06-01
3                21          1994-05-01
4                9           1992-05-22
4                20          1992-09-05
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner select group by the `class_id` and take only those that have different numbers of unique and total birthdays.

Then count those `class_id`s in the outer select.

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select class_id
    from your_table
    group by class_id
    having count(*) > count(distinct birthday)
) tmp
```

Comment: `count(birthday)` should be `count(*)`. Only put a column name when you're using `DISTINCT` or you need it to skip null values.

Comment: Same thing with `count(class_id)`. Just get out of the habit of using `count(colname)`, it's hardly ever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Write a subquery that finds all the duplicate birthdays in the same class. Then count the number of different classes with `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT class_id)` from that subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT class_id) FROM (
    SELECT class_id, birthday
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY class_id, birthday
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS x
```